# java.lang.ClassCastException: On custom composite component

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an activity that sets xml by calling the below xml. This xml layout inturn calls a custom composite component that sets up two buttons and an edittext. My main activity then trys to get the value from the edit text defined by the custom composite component. I have the logcat report below, but cannot see what it is I am not getting correct.

XML Layout File

```
        <com.android.control.MinutePicker
            android:id="@+id/MinPick"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </com.android.control.MinutePicker>
```

com.android.control.MinutePicker

```
but1 = new Button( context );
but1.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
but1.setText( "-" );
but2 = new Button( context );
but2.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
but2.setText( "-" );
valueText = new EditText( context );
valueText.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
valueText.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );
valueText.setText(0);
this.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
LayoutParams elementParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ELEMENT_WIDTH, ELEMENT_HEIGHT );

    addView( but1, elementParams );
    addView( valueText, elementParams );
    addView( but2, elementParams );
```

Main activity that then trys to get the value of the edit text.

```
             EditText Identifier = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MinPick);
             String value = Identifier.getText().toString();
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(PerfectSleepActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
             toast.show();
```

LogCat report

```
05-08 19:03:56.141: E/AndroidRuntime(200): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.control.MinutePicker
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.ap.df.DFActivity$2.onClick(PerfectSleepActivity.java:37)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4133)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6510)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3672)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1712)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1202)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1987)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1696)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
05-08 19:03:57.730: E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to cast a class of type MinutePicker (com.android.control.MinutePicker) to EditText on this line of code:

```
EditText Identifier = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MinPick);
```

R.id.MinPick is of type MinutePicker, not EditText.

This will not work. Does MinutePicker inherit from EditText or something? Please post the class identifier (not just the code contained in it).

Maybe you mean to do the following:

```
MinutePicker mp = (MinutePicker)findViewById(R.id.MinPick);
```